# python doesn't recognize a folder

Tags: python, import, pycharm, package

I'm working on linux ubuntu 20.04. I opened new python project using Pycharm IDE, and I've installed a package called `aihwkit`, the [documentation](https://aihwkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the [source](https://github.com/IBM/aihwkit).

When running the examples given with the source code, which use modules imported from a directory called `inference` such as example `06_lenet5_hardware_aware.py` I'm getting an error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aihwkit.inference'`

although other folders, in the same directory as `inference` are imported as well and they work well. I'm trying to import this manually, but not sure how to do it.

This is the hierarchy of the folders: I'm calling inference like this:
`from aihwkit.inference import PCMLikeNoiseModel`
from the file `examples/06_lenet5_hardware_aware.py` when the module `PCMLikeNoiseModel` source code lies in the following path: `src/aihwkit/inference/noise/pcm.py`

please note that the problem is that the name `aihwkit.inference` is not found, while other names such as `aihwkit.nn` do not raise any error, and they reside in similar path to `inference`.

I'm adding a picture of the hierarchy in case it helps:

[image]

how can I import this folder manually?

Thank you

Comment: Could you check the content of the different `__init__.py` files. Maybe you redefine the same symbol name (as a module name), and that would have priority. Else: check exactly the Python error. Which module cause the exception. Some modules may be written so that they expect to have (also) a different root (so pip installed, or just with correct addition in PYTHONPATH)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Linux, you can try to install your package before importing it with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-#name_of_your_package
```

written in your terminal, or you can try to install it with `pip`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I've already installed the package `aihwkit`. for some reason the python interpreter sees all the folders in `src` except for `inference`, so i'm trying to somehow force the interpreter to see it. I cannot install `inference` using pip, it's not a single package, it comes with `aihwkit`...

Comment: Maybe it's a problem related to CUDA support. You might have to use an _inplace_ command to set your CUDA, such as `python setup.py build_ext --inplace -DUSE_CUDA=ON` and then include your aihwkit path. For further information you can have a look [here](https://githubmemory.com/repo/IBM/aihwkit/issues/289)

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's my post actually... I've followed their instructions and I'm still getting the same problem. perhaps I did something wrong when running the commands, but I'm not sure what, that's why I'm trying to add the folder manually